# How to execute curl command generated by for loop in bash shell?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, curl

I have generated curl command from the for loop.

```
for ((i=1; i<=1000; i++)); do  
echo "curl http://example.com/page.php?page=$i"; done
```

For now it prints desired curl command. Instead of just printing the curl command i want to execute the curl command. How do i make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not simply: `curl "http://example.com/page.php?page=$i"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved by simply removing the echo command as suggested by @PesaThe.

```
for ((i=1; i<=1000; i++)); do  
curl "http://example.com/page.php?page=$i"; done
```

Thanks @PesaThe .